# Como faço no JavaScript para checar se meu input tem algum texto escrito?

Tags: javascript, html5, front-end, booleano

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```js
function aviso() {
  document.querySelector(".registers_button")
  let email_box = document.querySelector(".email")
  if (email_box.innerHTML == '') {
    alert("Por favor, preencha os campos obrigatórios")
  } else if (!email_box.innerHTML == '') {
    alert("Redirecionando...")
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="email_text"> E-mail: <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Jhon_90@example.com"> </p>
```

Comment: Não legende seus `<input>` com `<p>` use [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Ex: `<label class="email_text"> E-mail: <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Jhon_90@example.com"> </label>`. Também veja [<input type="email">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email)

Comment: Opa amigão, muito obrigado, farei essa alteração no meu código. Aos poucos vou aprendendo HTML semântico.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta precisa de mais esclarecimentos, mas supondo que seu elemento com a classe "email" é um input e não um elemento como DIV, a forma correta de buscar o valor do campo é usando value, não innerHTML

```
if (email_box.value == '') {
    alert ("Campo vazio");
} else {
    alert("Redirecionando")
}
```

innerHTML e innerText são propriedades de elementos como `<div>`, `<p>` etc.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado ! tua resposta foi exatamente oque eu buscava. Quanto a pergunta, preciso mesmo melhorar.

Comment: se a resposta está de acordo com o que procurava marque-a como "Resposta aceita" =)

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem duas TAGs um `p` e um `input`:

Se quiser obter o texto dentro do `<p>` (um HTMLElement) você pode usar o `innerText`:

```js
let txt = globalThis.document.querySelector("p.email_text").innerText
console.log("RESULTADO:", txt);
```

```html
<p class="email_text"> E-mail: <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Jhon_90@example.com"> </p>
```

---

```
<input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Jhon_90@example.com">
```

Se quer obter um texto dentro de um `input` (HTMLInputElement), você pode usar o `value`.

```js
let txt = globalThis.document.querySelector("input.email").value
console.log("RESULTADO:", txt);
```

```html
<p class="email_text"> E-mail: <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: Jhon_90@example.com" value="um valor"> </p>
```